# 1 UIImagePickerController and 2 buttons

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

i have an UIImagePickerController and 2 buttons. When I tap on button 1 I want to set the image of button 1. And when I tap on button 2 I want to set the image of button 2. I've successfully set the image of button 1 using UIImagePickerController but failed to do so with button 2. Here's my code:

```
var whichButton: Int = 0

func displayImagePicker(){

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func chooseImageOne(sender: AnyObject) {

    displayImagePicker()

    whichButton = 1

}

@IBAction func chooseImageTwo(sender: AnyObject) {

    displayImagePicker()

    whichButton = 2

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    if whichButton == 1 {

        self.imageOne.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    } else if whichButton == 2 {

        self.imageTwo.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
}
```

As you can see I tried having a var to keep track of which button I'm tapping on. I'm not sure what I've done in the didFinishPickingImage func is right. I'm very new to swift, if anyone can shed some light it will really be great! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have personally checked your code on xcode and its correct. Please see if you have given IBOutlet to self.imageTwo button and also check for the IBAction i.e touchupInside for the imageTwo button. else everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Your code is functionally correct. Looks like your `@IBAction` functions are not hooked up correctly, or the `@IBOutlet` of the second button. You could easily check this with print statements in the button handlers, or in the debugger.

Comment: sorry I'm very new to swift, can you go into a bit more detail about how I can check that in the debugger? thanks

Comment: If you do not know how to use the debugger, use print statements. To learn how to use Xcode, look for tutorials online or go to developer.apple.com.

Comment: ok so i checked and the functions are hooked up correctly, any idea why the codes are still not working?

Comment: Also check the outlets.